# Trying to calculate on each day how many products were sold accross all departments

Tags: postgresql

```
DO 
 $$BEGIN
       EXECUTE FORMAT('create table prouduct_pivots AS ' || 
               'SELECT * FROM  CROSSTABLE(%L, %L) AS ct(day date, %s)',
               'SELECT DATE_TRUNC(''day'', s.transation_date) AS day, product.name, count(*) cnt FROM sale s, product p WHERE s.product_id = product.id GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(''day'', sale.transation_date), product.name
               ORDER BY 1'
               'SELECT DISTINCT name FROM product ORDER BY 1',
               (SELECT STRING_AGG(replace(name, '', '_') || 'text', ',') FROM product ORDER BY 1)
);

END$$;
SELECT * FROM product_pivot;
```

Comment: And what problem are you having with it? Also, I don't see any PHP in here.

Comment: Hi Gigi21. That's a nice complex query. Can you please tell us a bit more about it? What does it do, what do you want it to do. Any specific problems with it?

Comment: each row have to contain the amount of products sold for each day ordered by the day.

Comment: Please add any information you have in your question. Useful information like database structure, what you're trying to accomplish, what you have tried, where it goes wrong, any questions you might have.

Comment: Edit your question and add create script, sample datas and expected result.

Comment: Could you tell us what the function CROSSTABLE() does? And what problems you're facing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.